# Open browser window in full screen using Selenium WebDriver with C#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

How can I make browser enter to fullscreen mode? Same as pressing F11.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

isn't that simple?

Answer (score 7):

For Python, just use

`driver.maximize_window()`

And it's done!

Comment: For Python this works. Based on the question tags it's meant to be C# but this helps too in-case

Answer (score 4):

Find the body and then send F11 to that like below.

```
driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).SendKeys(Keys.F11);
```

Comment: almost works =) driver.FindElement(By.TagName("html")).SendKeys(Keys.F11); - is better =)

Comment: In my case, Pressing F11 works for Firefox and IE, But not for Chrome by using the code: driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body")).SendKeys(Keys.F11);

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you know but you can set the size and position of your window as well

```
webDriver.Manage().Window.Position = new Point(x, y);
webDriver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(width, height);
```

Comment: Although this didn't answer the F11. +1 As it also me to test at different resolutions.

Answer (score 3):

In selenium/ Python: for maximizing window:

`driver.maximize_window()`

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions you need to access the webdriver directly so it would be,

```py
driver.maximize_window()
```

**P.S** This is the *python* API.